# Batch filename files from two columns on a list

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have about 1000 plus files of various file extensions. I also have a tab delimited text file with oldname and new file-names in side by side columns. For eg:

```
old       new
file1    entirely_new_name_for_file_1
file2    entirely_new_name_for_file_2
file3    entirely_new_name_for_file_3
```

How will I go about  batch rename all these files using shell script ?

Answer (score 4):

If you already have them in file then run a loop like this:

```
while read old new; do
    mv "$old" "$new"
done < "file"
```

Comment: And done. Works perfectly. Spent 2 hours of my own to get this to work . But I think it was worth it :0

Answer (score 1):

you can use HEREDOC as well:

```
while read old new; do
    mv $old $new
done <<___HERE
    file1    entirely_new_name_for_file_1
    file2    entirely_new_name_for_file_2
    file3    entirely_new_name_for_file_3
___HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

here's another method. I would not use it myself, it feels risky:

```
sed 's/^/mv /' filename | sh
```

If the first line is actually a header, then `sed '1d;s/^/mv /'`